# Error while run the maven framework through command prompt but it's running fine with eclipse

Tags: maven, selenium

I faced  the issue with the surefire plugin "2.19.1" as below. I have tried with the version 2.19.1,2.12.4,3.0.0-M1

[image]

Comment: Please don't post the relevant things as images. That's not useful for anyone trying to search same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're maven seems to be corrupt. Assuming you're on a windows machine:

1) set M2_HOME environment variable to the folder where maven is. (if in doubt [download](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi?Preferred=ftp%3A%2F%2Fapache.cs.utah.edu%2Fapache.org%2F) it and put it somewhere, it's just a java program.

2) set JAVA_HOME environment variable to the folder where your java is.

3) add %JAVA_HOME%/bin:%M2_HOME%/bin to the start of your PATH environment variable.

4) Make sure your ~/.m2/ folder has a settings.xml in it, you can use the one from the maven download to start. (you may need to add the [proxy details](https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/set-proxy-for-maven-in-eclipse.html))

5) Test with

```
mvn -version
```

6) You can clear your local repository by deleting files in ~/.m2/repository if you've not done much and have a reasonable network just blow the whole thing away.